# Custom subdomain support with Cloudflare DNS and Netlify Pages

Tags: domain-name-system, cloudflare

I have a saas app say `abc.com` serving from Netlify Pages and DNS is managed by Cloudflare.

I have set up this by adding `CNAME/A` in Cloudflare which points to `abc.netlify.app/IP`. Now I want my users to be able to set up their subdomain say `new/anything.xyz.com` to be able to point to `abc.com`

**Notes**

1. App is hosted with Netlify pages
2. DNS is managed by Cloudflare

**Expected flow**

1. User choose a subdomain from their dashboard (of our saas product), lets call it `company1` and what he see is `company1.abc.com`
2. Now I want my customers to be able to use `company1.abc.com` as their redirect domain from their website say `xyz.co`, `ab.xyz.co` or `anything.any.co`. Expecting them to add `company1.abc.com` as a `CNAME` for their required domain.

Is this doable, then how? TA.

Answer (score 1):

As i know netlify need to define the custom domain first before you can add the CNAME record on DNS Zone.

So make sure the new.abc.com added to your custom domain list : https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/

Comment: Tried that, but no luck.